# How to append a empty row to a list/table which is bound to a OData(List Binding) in sapui5?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have have a list/table which is bound to a entitySet from OData Model V2. I have a add(+) button on screen on clicking that button a empty row(s) need to be appended to the list/table. After that if I enter any data that should be saved into the backend on clicking of save button.

This is possible using JSONModel, but I want to use the OData model .

Regards,
Suman Kumar

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please expand your query with relevant code and errors where relavant. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

It does work with two way data binding.

You can do that using [odataModel](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel) createEntry method.

The createEntry expects a parameter, the path to your entitySet that you want to create (It should be something like XXXXset). Imagine the following:

1 - User clicks an "Add" button that renders a dialog Window with some fields and two buttons (save and cancel) for him to add his brand new entity.

2 - On the "open event" before you open the dialog, you create a new entity with the createEntry method. Its return gives you a context that you can bind to the dialog.

```
that.contextCursoIniciativaEmpregadoASerCriada = that.getView().getModel().createEntry('/CursoIniciativaEmpregadoSet');

that.fragmentCriacaoDadosInicEmpregado.bindElement(that.contextCursoIniciativaEmpregadoASerCriada.sPath);

that.fragmentCriacaoDadosInicEmpregado.open();
```

3 - The dialog pops up with the bind in place.

4 - The user fills the dialog with the entities properties

5 - The user clicks on the save button and you submit your changes

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Geraldo,
Appreciate if you could elaborate a little more. As there is no clear documentation available. does it works with only two-way binding only?